# How do I return all strings containing a "£" in them?

Tags: python, web-scraping, full-text-search

I'm trying to web scrape a site that is badly designed and I am trying to gather the prices of items. The only thing in common with each page is that the prices all start with a "£" so I thought that if I searched through all the HTML content and returned all strings with "£" attached it would work.

I am not quite sure how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: You can use regular expression `re.match(r"^£.*", "your string")`

Comment: a link to the page might be helpful for other users to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pull out the prices with '£' prefix then can try something like this.

```python
import re

html = """
cost of living is £2,232
bottle of milk costs £1 and it goes up to £1.05 a year later...
"""

print(re.findall(r"£\S+", html))
```

**Output:**

```
['£2,232', '£1', '£1.05']
```

If you want to extract the item name along with the price then the regexp will need to be modified. [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Python library can be used to extract info from even malformed HTML sites.

Comment: I suspect extracting the item name is non-trivial

Comment: Thank you for your response @CodeMonkey! I will also try that. What do you think of this potential solution also: ` all_html = response.css('html').get()
            for line in all_html.split('\n'):
                for word in line.split():
                    if word.startswith('£'):
                        print (word)`

Comment: @Bastion Splitting on `\n`  in HTML is uncommon but hard to say w/o seeing the raw HTML. Sounds like the content is just plain text and not enclosed by tags.